# Implement next combination - C_n_k on C++ using vector

Tags: c++, combinatorics

I am getting stuck - can't implement perfect algorithm for next Combination for lexicographical order. Could you please tell me where I get wrong? For instance, e.g. vector a = {1,2,0,3,0,1,2,4}; nextPermutation(a); has an overflow-heap when accessing to an element of the array std::next. How would this code be improved?

```
   void nextPermutation(vector<int>& perm) {
        auto temp1 = perm[0], temp2 = perm[0];
        int idx1 = -1, idx2 = -1;
        if (perm.size() == 1)
            return;
        if (perm.size() == 2)
        {
            reverse(perm.begin(), perm.end());
            return;
        }
        for (auto &v : perm)
        {
            if (&v - &perm[0] == perm.size())
                break;
            if (v < *(&v + 1))
            {
                temp1 = v;
                idx1 = &v  - &perm[0];
                //cout << idx1 << endl;
            }
        }
        if (idx1 == -1)
        {
            reverse(perm.begin(), perm.end());
            return;
        }
        for (auto v = perm.begin(); v < perm.end(); v++)
        {
            if (*v > *next(perm.begin(), idx1))
            {
                temp2 = *v;
                idx2 = std::distance(perm.begin(), v);
                //cout << idx2 << endl;
            }
        }
        int temp = perm[idx1];
        perm[idx1] = perm[idx2];
        perm[idx2] = temp;
        reverse(perm.begin() + idx1 + 1, perm.end());
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce (maybe show us the code that calls your function?) However, I think you should change your first `for` loop (to determine `idx1`) to the same form as the second (`idx2`) loop, using `1` as the 2nd argument to `std::next`. Works for me and looks *much* safer.

Comment: @AdrianMole https://ideone.com/DIpu11 Yep, first loop should ideally find last x: perm[x] < perm[x+1]. I wrongly use &v - &perm[0] == perm.size() - I am trying to determine wether the loop has reached last element, so that next if won't run; I think there is a simple way to check it.

Comment: `for (auto v = perm.begin(); v < perm.end() - 1; v++)` runs to the last-but-one element.